# Boost spirit x3: compound attribute compile time error (enum class)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I was recently writing a simplest possible parser using *boost spirit x3*. It contains 2 rules: **identifier** and a single character **operator**. Naturally, I implemented the **operator** using a symbol table, which produces an operator type `enum class`. **Identifiers** are parsed as `std::string`s. However, the code refuses to compile when combining identifiers and operators into a single parser (see the code piece at the end of the question).

Note, that if you change operator type enum with an integer, everything works fine. Operators and identifiers are parsed well when separate too.

The template error message is quite big to be attached and too obscure for me to understand, but I suspect it has something to do with construction/move semantic of `std::variant<std::string, OperType>`. However, `enum class` should not be drastically different from the plain `int`. Does it have anything to do with `enum class` default constructor? How this can be bypassed?

Here is the codepiece

```cpp
#include <variant>
#include <string>

#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

auto addCharacter = [](auto &context) {
    x3::_val(context).push_back(x3::_attr(context));
};

x3::rule<class IdentifierTag, std::string> identifier{"identifier"};
const auto identifier_def = x3::lexeme[x3::char_("a-zA-Z")[addCharacter] >> *(x3::char_("a-zA-Z0-9")[addCharacter])];

BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(identifier);

enum class OperType
{
    plus,
    minus
};

struct Opers_ : x3::symbols<OperType>
{
    Opers_()
    {
        add("+", OperType::plus)("-", OperType::minus);
    }
} opers_;

x3::rule<class OperTypeTag, OperType> oper{"operator"};
const auto oper_def = x3::lexeme[opers_];

BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(oper);

int main()
{
    std::string input{"iden1 + - iden2"};

    std::vector<std::variant<std::string, OperType>> tokens;

    auto start = input.cbegin();
    auto result = x3::phrase_parse(start, input.cend(), (+(identifier | oper)), x3::space, tokens);

    return 0;
}
```

Are there any pitfalls when writing compound parsers? What am I missing? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::variant` is not yet supported for attribute compatibility.

Changing to `boost::variant` makes it compile: **[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/PP633T)**

> Alternatively, here are ways to make it actually work if you **require** std::variant: [Transitioning Boost Spirit parser from boost::variant to std::variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61392947/transitioning-boost-spirit-parser-from-boostvariant-to-stdvariant/61409717#61409717)

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <variant>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <fmt/ostream.h>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

auto addCharacter = [](auto& context) {
    x3::_val(context).push_back(x3::_attr(context));
};

x3::rule<class IdentifierTag, std::string> identifier{"identifier"};
const auto identifier_def =
    x3::lexeme[x3::char_("a-zA-Z")[addCharacter] >> *(x3::char_("a-zA-Z0-9")[addCharacter])];

BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(identifier)

enum class OperType
{
    plus,
    minus
};

static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, OperType ot) {
    switch(ot) {
        case OperType::plus: return os << "plus";
        case OperType::minus: return os << "minus";
    }
    return os << "?";
}

struct Opers_ : x3::symbols<OperType>
{
    Opers_()
    {
        add("+", OperType::plus)
           ("-", OperType::minus);
    }
} opers_;

x3::rule<class OperTypeTag, OperType> oper{"operator"};
const auto oper_def = x3::lexeme[opers_];

BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(oper)

int main() {
    std::string const input{"iden1 + - iden2"};

    std::vector<boost::variant<std::string, OperType>> tokens;

    auto f = input.begin(), l = input.end();
    auto result = x3::phrase_parse(
            f, l,
            +(identifier | oper),
            x3::space,
            tokens);

    if (result) {
        fmt::print("Parsed: {}\n", tokens);
    } else {
        fmt::print("Parse failed\n");
    }

    if (f!=l) {
        fmt::print("Remaining: '{}'\n", std::string(f,l));
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Parsed: {iden1, plus, minus, iden2}
```

Comment: Also with 20 lines of code less: https://godbolt.org/z/Eozchn

Comment: Thank you very much for our continuous help! It seems this detail is not significantly mentioned in spirit x3 documentation or I accidentally missed it.